# How to connect Azure Cosmos DB to MongoDB Compass

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, mongodb-compass

I am having trouble connecting my Azure CosmosDB to MongoDB Compass. I need clarification and assistance with the following settings:

- Authentication = username and password from connection string?
- Authentication Database = my CosmosDB database?
- Replica Set Name?
- Read Preference = Primary?
- SSL?
- SSH Tunnel?

Answer (score 7):

Cosmos DB uses Username/Keys instead of Username/Password authentication. In the Azure Portal for your Azure Cosmos DB instance, under Settings > Connection String, you will see your Connection Strings. It's all there:

[image]

Primary Connection String Example:
mongodb://**miubezzi-mongoapi**:'Read-write Key'@miubezzi-mongoapi.documents.azure.com:10255/?**ssl**=true&**replicaSet**=globaldb

With the following Compass Connect information, I was able to connect. My Compass instance is currently syncing but I am connected. Will update with addition details.

[image]

[image]

And I am able to create a Database + Collection via Compass.

[image]

Comment: this is only valid for CLI mongodb though? I am posting regarding CosmosDB Compass here

Comment: Let me take a look. I am seeing a bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-2990

Comment: So I'm guessing until the bug gets resolved (which they won't), one cannot access the data within mongodb hosted on azure cosmosdb? I arrived at the stage where Compass keeps on trying to load the data too.

Comment: Let me reach out to the product group and get you some additional information.

Comment: In the meantime, I see that this is not an existing ask on the Cosmos DB User Voice: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db Please make an entry there, as I know the product group is going to redirect me there first. I already have a communication out to them. I need you to make a feature request on the User Voice. Thank you!

Comment: Same here. I have created the User Voice entry, as @MikeUbezziMSFT suggested: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/36349687-compass-connection-not-showing-documents-but-all

Comment: The User Voice entry is the correct channel for this feature request. I have sent an email to the product group but they are not going to respond. The User Voice forum is the best method for this ask. Thank you!